# Active Admin: Is it possible to add an href to an f.input hint string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to add an external link to an active admin form input hint

```
form do |f|
  f.input :catalog_icon,
    hint: "Use a font-awesome icon class name, e.g. 'fas fa-star'."\
    " See https://fontawesome.com/icons/ for a list of available icons."
...
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know I could just pass `.html_safe` to the hint string, to render a hint with html.
i.e.

```
form do |f|
  f.input :catalog_icon,
    hint: "Use a font-awesome icon class name, e.g. 'fas fa-star'."\
    " See <a href=\"https://fontawesome.com/icons/\">fontawesome</a>"\
    " for a list of available icons.".html_safe
...
end
```